# Is it possible to declare array as a instance variable?

Tags: java

Is it possible to declare array as instance variable?

```
public class Dog 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Some code like creating objects
    }
}

class Dogtesr
{
    int[] nums;
    nums = new int[5]; // This shows an error
}
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Is the programming language you're using called "arrays" or "instance-variables"?

Answer (score 6):

Statements (`nums = new int[5];`) (as opposed to variable / method / class declarations) needs to be in functions, e.g. the constructor:

```
class Dogtesr
{
   int[] nums;
   public Dogtesr()
   {
      nums = new int[5];
   }
}
```

Or you can simply initialize `nums` as part of the declaration:

```
int[] nums = new int[5];
```